# How to delete many documents with Beanie ODM linked documents

Tags: mongodb, motor-asyncio

I am following the example of the Beanie ODM docs on how to delete a single document:
https://beanie-odm.dev/tutorial/relations/#delete

passing `link_rule=DeleteRules.DELETE_LINKS` to the `delete` method.
For a single document that works, but when i try that with multiple documents like this:

```
await House.find().delete(link_rule=DeleteRules.DELETE_LINKS)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Collection.delete_many() got an unexpected keyword argument 'link_rule'
```

**Question:**
How can i delete many documents in Beanie ODM once after filtering with `find`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this.

According with their docs https://beanie-odm.dev/tutorial/relations/#delete

> Find operations with the fetch_links parameter can not be used in the chaning with delete and update methods.

In this case your option would be to query your child items and then delete one by one or run a find with their ids and then you chain with delete.